# PF Autocomplete completemethod is not being triggered

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, view, autocomplete

I'm working on a project using JSF 2 & Primefaces 5 where navigation is done entirely by ajax. When getting into a page with a basic autocomplete component, the complete method is not being triggered. When refreshing the page, then the complete method is working. Sample of the autocomplete:

```
<label for="name">Your name <em>*</em></label> <br/>
<p:autoComplete id="name" value="#{myBean.name}"
     completeMethod="#{myBean.complete}" required="true"
     requiredMessage="Please enter a name"
     placeholder="enter something..." />
```

Backing bean method:

```
public List<String> complete(String query){
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(nameData name: this.namesData){
        if(name.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase())){
            result.add(name);
        }
        if(result.size() == 5){
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Have been searching for this and found possible solutions, tryed implementing them but didn't fix this problem. Seems weird since the posts on this problem were dated from a older version of PF (3.X). FYI;

adding this script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        PrimeFaces.escapeRegExpOld = PrimeFaces.escapeRegExp;
        PrimeFaces.escapeRegExp = function(c) {
            var t = PrimeFaces.escapeRegExpOld(c);
            t = t.replace('&amp;', '&amp;amp;');
            return t;
        };
 </script>
```

Adding this function and calling it when autocomplete gets focus

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function escapeTerm(request) {
                request.term = encodeURIComponent(request.term);
            }
 </script>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is that a typo or is there actually a mismatch between the configured `completeMethod` and what you have written as the complete method?

Comment: If things appear to be failing in client side, always look in browser's JS console and HTTP traffic monitor for clues. Sometimes, the server log may also contain hints/clues.

Comment: @kolossus yes, it was a typing error. I've edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after debugging a lot I could found a solution. Despite this, I don't quite know the cause for this bug.

After implementing a copy of the Autocomplete Renderer of primefaces I've noticed when debbuging that the decode method wasn't executed, so the complete method wasn't triggered. I thought this was because the component didn't appear on the component Tree from the view root (printed it on log to check), so on the Invoke Application Phase it couldn't decode the component after input something for auto-completing... Then I encounter this piece of code on the "encodeScript" method.

```
f (context.isProjectStage(ProjectStage.Development)) {
        if (ac.getAttributes().containsKey("process")
                || ac.getAttributes().containsKey("global")
                || ac.getAttributes().containsKey("onstart")
                || ac.getAttributes().containsKey("oncomplete")) {
            LOG.warning("The process/global/onstart/oncomplete attribute of AutoComplete was removed. Please use p:ajax with the query event now");
        }
    }
```

Since my project is on Development I thought this was the problem. So I took into account the log message. When debugging this code, the log warning wasn't printed since those attributes weren't present on autocomplete object. Despite this I used a query ajax event instead of a completemethod and then the decode was being executed, even though the complete method didn't trigger. After a couple of tries I got it working as follow:

```
<label for="name">Your name <em>*</em></label> <br/>
<p:autoComplete id="name" value="#{myBean.name}"
     completeMethod="#{myBean.complete}" required="true"
     requiredMessage="Please enter a name"
     placeholder="enter something..." >
   <p:ajax event="query" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

Hope it helps. If someone can clarify more than me, please post the cause of this.